# AddGpsStatusListener of location manager not working in android 10

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I used location manager for change status of GPS in navigation app.
But it not working in *android 10* (samsung a10).
Unfortunately broadcast receiver is limited in android 10.

**My code is:**

```
locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new GpsStatus.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
                switch (event) {
                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "GpsStatusChanged started");
                        
                        break;

                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "GpsStatusChanged stopped");
                        break;

                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                        break;

                    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

How to resolve it?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addGpsStatusListener` is deprecated in `API level 24`.
Please use `LocationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(GnssStatus.Callback)` instead.

More info, go to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#registerGnssStatusCallback(android.location.GnssStatus.Callback,%20android.os.Handler))

Answer (score 0):

Yes when I updated the target to API 33 , it fails and says its deprecated. But this will work till API 31 [see this link](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/467)

We need to use the GnssStatus as given in the [code example](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/driversamples/GpsActivity.java)